# OpenCV - Finding the outline of Canny edges

Tags: python, opencv, canny-operator

I have used Canny edge detector to detect the edges of an image. The results are shown below:

[image: Imgur][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7NyP.jpg)

I would like to remove everything except for the outline of the edges. The desired output is shown below:

[image: Imgur][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7NyP.jpg)

I have tried a series of morphological transformations (specifically eroding/dilating and opening/closing), however, these transformations also removed the outline of the image. I tried using median blurring, but that also removed the outline edges.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the `Region of Interest` by selecting five points of a polygon like the one shown and use `Numpy`'s `polyfit` function to fit lines of a polygon and `meshgrid` to find region inside, to mask the edges inside your selected region and obtain everything else from outside.

[image]